# Copy and overwrite sheet from closed workbook to another closed workbook

Tags: excel, vba

A begineer here need help. I have 4 excel files. Excel1 have sheetname report1. Excel2 have sheetname report2. Excel3 (my main report excel file). Excel4 (my tracking excel file).

The excel number 1,2,3 are closed and only the Excel4 is open.
I want to make a VBA script that if click a button at Excel4 will copy/overwrite the sheetnames(report1 and report2) to Excel3 (my main report excel file).
Really appreciates if someone can help/guide me how to start the code or please share if have already VBA script available almost similar. Thanks.

Comment: I believe this is difficult task...Really need guidance from experts...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check with this,

```
Sub CopySheets()
    
    With Application
    
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    End With
    
    'Path for Excel3 file
    Dim strFilename3 As String: strFilename3 = "E:\SO1\Excel3.xlsx"
    
    Set wb3 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFilename3)
    
    'Path for Excel1 file
    Dim strFilename1 As String: strFilename1 = "E:\SO1\Excel1.xlsx"
    
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFilename1)
    
    'Each worksheet in a workbook
    For Each ws1 In wb1.Worksheets
        
        If ws1.Name = "report1" Then
            
            'copy sheet name to a variable
            'str1 = ws1.Name
            ws1.Copy Before:=Workbooks("Excel3.xlsx").Sheets(1)
            
        End If
    
    Next ws1
    
    wb1.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    'Path for Excel2 file
    Dim strFilename2 As String: strFilename2 = "E:\SO1\Excel2.xlsx"
    
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFilename2)
    
    'Each worksheet in a workbook
    For Each ws2 In wb2.Worksheets
        
        If ws2.Name = "report2" Then
            
            'copy sheet name to a variable
            'str2 = ws2.Name
            ws2.Copy Before:=Workbooks("Excel3.xlsx").Sheets(1)
            
            
        End If
    
    Next ws2
    
    wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    wb3.Close SaveChanges:=True
    
    
    With Application
    
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    
    End With

    MsgBox ("Completed")
    
End Sub
```